# How to split a toll free number into the number and extension?

Tags: java, regex, split

I have a few toll free numbers with their extensions, like this:

1. `(888) 716-9293 x298`
2. `1800 888 321 opt 2`

I want to split this string into: `{"(888) 716-9293","x298"}` and make that number as a telephone link for my mobile app. (I'm using `tel:` for that).

I have tried the `split()` function with the simple regex `[a-zA-Z]+` but it's not printing correct results! So, how to split a toll free number into the number and extension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\\s(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

or

```
[ ](?=[a-zA-Z]
```

Try this.Split by this.This should work.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/fG5pZ8/7

Comment: Hey, Thank you so much. It works fine! And thasnks for that regex tool link! :)